# "Data Type" argument can not be null

Tags: c#

I am getting an error when trying to execute the application in .Net near the column (premium to date) (Highlighted in the code below) and this is the newly added column in my application and after adding it I was not able to run the application .

```
private DataView getPremiumsFromCoverages()
    {
        DataTable dtPremium = new DataTable("Premium");

        dtPremium.Columns.Add(COLUMN_PREMIUM_BREAKDOWN, System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dtPremium.Columns.Add(COLUMN_PREMIUM_PERCENT, System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
        dtPremium.Columns.Add(COLUMN_PREMIUM, System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dtPremium.Columns.Add(COLUMN_PREMIUM_HAZARDLEVEL, System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        **dtPremium.Columns.Add(COLUMN_PREMIUMTODATE, System.Type.GetType("system.Decimal"));**

        OptionEXC currOption = this._Account.CurrentRisk.Options.FindBy_OptionNum(this.OptionNum);
        CoverageEXC covEXC;
        HazardLevelCollection hazardLevelColl = new HazardLevelCollection();
```

Comment: What in the world?! What are you using `GetType` to pull `System` types?

Comment: @user1567194 what people are saying is instead of `System.Type.GetType("System.String")` use `typeof(String)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mistyped System.Decimal as system.Decimal.

Comment: but you really should be using `typeof(Decimal)`

Comment: Or `typeof(decimal)` - which doesn't require the `using System;` to exist, as `decimal` is provided by the language.

Comment: I would say you should even include something to the effect of "but you should really use `typeof(Decimal)`" in your answer

Comment: I have been using this in my code everywhere and I did not come across this problem as we are saying typeof(decimal) so is there something going around it

Comment: It's certainly best to use `typeof` when the type is (accessible and) in an assembly that is already referenced, since errors like this will show up compile-time. It is however interesting to note that there's an overload of the static `Type.GetType` to accomplish (1) an exception to be thrown instead of just silently returning `null` when the type is not found, and (2) allow the type string to be case-insensitive. Both behaviors related to the error the Original Poster has.